# How to restrict selection, only within the option group in multiple selection of bootstrap selectpicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

In bootstrap select-picker, for multiple selection, how to restrict selection only within an option group. Means, if some items are selected within an option group and a new selection is made in another option group, the previous selections should clear and only the new selection remain.

Comment: tag the plugin  you're using, if no tag is available, provide a link to it in question, share the code you've so far.. doing such things will help those trying to help you. please read [ask]. At the moment it looks like you're giving us a set of requirements and expect us do do your work from scratch.

Comment: it's a mistake, the question mistakenly was added, I wanted to post an answer :(

Comment: *"how to restrict selection only within an option group"* doesn't sound like an answer... anyway you got an answer for your *supposed to be answer post* within minutes.. lol

Comment: :D I don't know how the hell it got posted... anyway just added it in case someone might need it some day... got two down votes :D shit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the bootstrap select-picker https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

The HTML

```
<select class="selectpicker" title="Please Select" multiple data-max-options="4">
    <optgroup class="group1" label="GROUP1" data-max-options="2">
        <option class="group1_2 ">Item1</option>
        <option class="group1_2 ">Item2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup class="group2" label="GROUP2" data-max-options="2">
        <option class="group2_2 ">Item A</option>
        <option class="group2_2 ">Item B</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

The script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();

        var flagGroup1 = 0;
        var flagGroup2 = 0;

        $(".group1_2").click(function() {
            if (flagGroup2 >= 1) {
                $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
                $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('deselectAll');
                flagGroup2 = 0;
                flagGroup1 = 1;
            }
            if ($( this ).parent().hasClass("selected")) {
                if (flagGroup1 > 1) {
                    flagGroup1 = 1;
                } else {
                    flagGroup1 = 0;
                }
            } else {
                flagGroup1 = flagGroup1 + 1;
            }
        });

        $(".group2_2").click(function() {
            if (flagGroup1 >= 1) {
                $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
                $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('deselectAll');
                flagGroup1 = 0;
                flagGroup2 = 1;
            }
            if ($( this ).parent().hasClass("selected")) {
                if (flagGroup2 > 1) {
                    flagGroup2 = 1;
                } else {
                    flagGroup2 = 0;
                }
            } else {
                flagGroup2 = flagGroup2 + 1;
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```